Who should pay for "add-ons" to a contract
If after a contract is in place and works have started, then the offeror finds something that requires more money, should the offeree have to do it as part of the agreed installation/contract or is it the offeror's risk since they should have done their due diligence before offering the quote or should the offeree pay the extra if it's extra work to what would be generally assumed to be not standard.
Obviously if there's T&Cs this might cover this scenario, but what if it's just an itemised list with a price constituting the offer.
Some examples might be:

Contract to install software to a PC, but during installation it's discovered that the PC requires extra components for it to be possible to install said software.
New tarmac driveway, but when digging up the old, the material underneath was found to be clay instead of expected sand lets say, so extra charge due to extra skip / labour required.
Solar panels installation; planning paperwork is done, but it's then found that the current wiring in the house isn't up to the job, so extra charge for fuse box upgrade etc.

What would be your options in this event.  If the offeree wasn't made aware of this extra work before they entered the contract and the offeror had an opportunity to inspect could you insist they complete their contract despite the obstacles?
Perhaps either party at this point could exit the contract at this point, but perhaps a little complicated if the offeror already started works.

The scope and risk allocation
The entire purpose of a contract is define who is to do what (the scope) and allocate risk between the parties.
Ideally the contract will be clear on all of this, but not all contracts are that well drafted and, even then, disputes arise. For small contracts (which all of your examples are), it’s just not worth the time and effort to draft ironclad agreements because the risks are small.
Where there is a written scope, then things that fall outside the scope would normally be at the purchaser’s risk. The contract defines what the contractor will do; anything outside that is what they won’t do. Work that is incidental to the scope and so obvious it goes without saying, is included in the scope, but anything else is not. For example, a carpenter hired to build a wall would be expected to include the nails.
For all your examples, these are at the owner’s risk. These types of risks are so common in construction contracts that they have a name: latent conditions and, in larger contracts, a lot of negotiation turns on who will take the risk for the different types. However, the default is, unless the contract says the contractor is taking the risk, the owner is.
Now, there doesn’t have to be extra charges by the contractor - the owner can do the necessary work themselves or hire another contractor, but using the contractor that’s there is probably cheaper and easier.
For examples 1 and 3, if this were discovered before the work commenced, the contractor might agree to cancel the contract, with or without a fee for that. It could also happen for contract 2, but by the time it becomes apparent, the existing driveway has already been ripped out. Technically, the owner has breached the contract because the inability of the contractor to finish the work is due to something they are responsible for.

Thank you! Do you mean that the owner might agree to cancel the contract in your final paragraph?  Otherwise I’m not sure the last sentence makes sense as the owner hasn’t done anything wrong at that point.

@JonathanClark the owner is preventing the contractor from completing their obligations by not fixing whatever it is that is stopping them (PC hardware, clay, inadequate wiring etc.). This is just the same as if the owner locked the gate and denied access - a breach by the owner. Breaches can be acts or failures to act.
